# slideToggle with 2 column layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle, slidedown

I have a 2 column layout like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MDAeV/

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.columns {
    width: 97%;

}

.column-12-12 {

    width: 97%;
}

.image-series {
    max-width: 250px;
    display:inline-block;

}

.image {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 245px;
    height: 100px;
}

.content {
    display:none;

}
```

When I click on "How it works", it makes the element next to it slide down as well... I want it to stay put and only have the actual element that is toggled slide down. Can someone help me out and post a jsfiddle solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the text to slide on the blue image below?

Comment: your question is not clear to me. what exactly you want?

Comment: For example, if I click on "How it works" in the first column, first row, I want the second column to not move at all. The first column's behavior can stay the same and slide down in order to show the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to your `.image-series` class.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5qb8/1/)

To get what you really want, I think you will need to actually specify you columns. A quick and dirty example:

```
<div>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column-12-12">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="image-series">
                    <div class="image"></div>
                    <div class="how-it-works">
                        <hr/>How it works <span class="plus">+</span>

                        <hr/>
                        <div class="content">djjsd jdksaljds djskadjskad jkdsad jkdlsad jkdsadj jkdsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-series">
                    <div class="image"></div>
                    <div class="how-it-works">
                        <hr/>How it works <span class="plus">+</span>

                        <hr/>
                        <div class="content">djjsd jdksaljds djskadjskad jkdsad jkdlsad jkdsadj jkdsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="image-series">
                    <div class="image"></div>
                    <div class="how-it-works">
                        <hr/>How it works <span class="plus">+</span>

                        <hr/>
                        <div class="content">djjsd jdksaljds djskadjskad jkdsad jkdlsad jkdsadj jkdsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-series">
                    <div class="image"></div>
                    <div class="how-it-works">
                        <hr/>How it works <span class="plus">+</span>

                        <hr/>
                        <div class="content">djjsd jdksaljds djskadjskad jkdsad jkdlsad jkdsadj jkdsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS add:

```
.col {
    display:inline-block;
    width:48%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5qb8/2/)

On a side note I'd avoid using `<hr />` tags when you could use borders insted. A more semantic mark up could be:

```
<div class="how-it-works">
    <h2>How it works <span class="plus">+</span></h2>            
    <div class="content">djjsd jdksaljds djskadjskad jkdsad jkdlsad jkdsadj jkdsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad jkdlsad</div>
</div>
```

and style the `h2`

```
.how-it-works h2
{
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-top: 2px groove;
    border-bottom: 2px groove;
    padding:0.75em 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5qb8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `display: inline-block` on the `.image-series`. Having this affects the adjacent elements. What you can do is use `display: block` and have them `float: left`. If you want only two toggles in a row, we clear the float after every 2 blocks.

```
.image-series {
    max-width: 250px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.image-series:nth-child(2n+3) {
  clear: both;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D6QZ7/)**

Comment: is there a way to not have the element next to the toggled div slide down? For example, if I click on "How it works" in the first column, first row, I want the second column to not move at all. Is that possible?